# Is it possible to have such process represented in rabbitMq?

Tags: php, architecture, rabbitmq

There is a long running process(Excel report creation) in my web app that needs to be executed in a background.

Some details about the app and environment.

The app consists of many instances, where each client has separate one (with customized business logic) while everything is hosted on our server. The functionality that produces Excel is the same.

---

I'm planning to have one rabbitMq server installed. One part of app(Publisher) will take all report options from user and will put it into message. And some background job(Consumer) will consume it, produce report and send it via email.

However, there is a flaw in such design, where,say, users from one instance will queue lots of complicated reports(worth ~10 min of work) and a user from another instance will queue an easy one(1-2 mins) and he will have to wait until others will finish.

There could be separate queues for each app instance, but in that case I would need to create one consumer per instance. Given that there are 100+ instances atm, it doesn't look like a viable approach.

I was thinking if it's possible to have a script that checks all available queues(and consumers) and create a new consumer for a queue that doesn't have one. There are no limitations on language for consumer and such script.

Does that sound like a feasible approach? If not, please give a suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: as I understood your issue correctly you don't need users from instance B (light reports) to wait for reports'  generation of users of instance A (heavy reports)?

Comment: @gskillz Yes. The point is to have separate queues per instance and to have a script that would create consumers for queues that doesn't yet have a consumer.

Comment: I am with the impression that everything will lies on one server?

Comment: @gskillz Correct.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood topic correctly everything lies on one server - RabbitMQ, web application, different instances per client and messeges' consumers. In that case I rather put different topics per message (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html) and introduce consumer priorities (https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html). Based on that options during publishing of the message I will create combination of topic and priority of the message - publisher will know number of already sent reports per client, selected options and will decide is it high, low or normal priority.
Logic to pull messages based on that data will be in the consumer so consumer will not get heavy topics when there are in process already 3 (example).

Based on the total number of messages in the queue (its not accurate 100%) and previous topics and priorities you can implement kind of leaking bucket strategy in order to get control of resources- max 100 number of reports generated simultaneously.

You can consider using ZeroMQ (http://zeromq.org) for your case its maybe more suitable that RabbitMQ because is more simple and its broker less solution.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will look into it. Assuming that topics will route messages to different queues there would need to be separate consumers(at least one) for each queue. Is it technically feasible to produce consumers for each queue from one script that doesn't have one yet? Or it's a flawed approach?

Comment: To me is flawed approach - I rather stay with multiple consumers, load balancers, priorities and leave that to Publisher/subscriber pattern.

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a go.